# Why is the quantum Hall apparatus in the canonical ensemble?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect

Most explanations of the integer quantum Hall effect start out in the grand canonical ensemble, where the plateaus arise when the chemical potential (or equivalently the Fermi energy) is in the gaps between the Landau levels. However, they then usually continue with a statement that working at fixed chemical potential is actually imprecise as the system is in a canonical ensemble (i.e. fixed particle number,) and so we need to include disorder to get the plateaus. While I understand why disorder is needed if we work at fixed particle number, I don't understand why the experimental systems are assumed to be in the canonical ensemble to begin with. Don't electrons flow in/out of the material when you measure resistivity? If this is the case, why is working in the canonical ensemble justified?